# Creating & sharing a simple text file in Android 10

Tags: android, android-intent, privacy, android-10.0, file-sharing

I've had some trouble creating a function that writes a large chunk of raw data to a text file, and then shares that text file to be sent by email/whatsapp. Since Android 10 it's no longer possible to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDir()` due to privacy reasons. It now seems that my file is not visible to other apps, and thus can not be opened by them. My code is as follows:

Fragment responsible for exporting:

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val data: String = retrieveData() ?: return@withContext
                val file = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "export.xml")
                val outputStream =
                    requireContext().openFileOutput("export.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                outputStream.write(data.toByteArray())
                outputStream.close()

                val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file)

                val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
                    type = "text/plain"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_file_subject))
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                }
                startActivity(
                    Intent.createChooser(
                        shareIntent,
                        getString(R.string.share_file_subject)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
```

In the manifest:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="files"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

When using the Android Studio file explorer I can see that the file is created with the correct content. The Uri points to: `content://myApplicationId/files/export.xml` and the file is located on my device at `data/data/myApplicationId/files` but I can't seem to figure out how to make it accessible for other apps to open.

When opening it with for example the gmail app, it creates a new concept with the subject filled in but I'm getting a Toast from the gmail app saying 'Unable to add attachment'. The intent seems to fire properly so there are no exceptions occurring in my code. My guess is that the file is still not accessible for other apps for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Uri points to: content://myApplicationId/files/export.xml

But you are not using that `Uri`. You are using `Uri.fromFile()`:

```
            val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
                type = "text/plain"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_file_subject))
```

You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` on Android 7.0+, so you already applied a hack to get around that. It's just that now, on Android 10+, that hack has limited value.

So, replace `Uri.fromFile(file)` with `uri`. Also, include `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` as part of your `apply {}` lambda. And find where in your code you are configuring `StrictMode` and have it complain about `FileUriExposedException`, at least on `debug` builds.

---

In addition, your I/O is messed up.

```
            val file = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "export.xml")
            val outputStream =
                requireContext().openFileOutput("export.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Your code assumes that `openFileOutput()` puts its content in the location identified by `getExternalFilesDir()`, which is incorrect. Switch the latter line to:

```
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately I still get the same result. I'm not aware of any hacks I'm implementing so do you have a link to how to properly implement this without getting a FileUriExposedException?

Comment: @TimvandeWal: "I still get the same result" -- you have not really explained what the result is, in detail. `FileProvider` should work fine. See [this code](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v1.0/T34-Share/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/ui/roster/RosterListFragment.kt#L179-191) for an example of using `ACTION_SEND`. The `Uri` is prepared [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v1.0/T34-Share/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/ui/roster/RosterMotor.kt#L78-86).

Comment: @TimvandeWal: And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38200282/115145) for more on the `FileUriExposedException` that you should get on Android 7.0+ when using a `Uri.fromFile()` value in an `Intent`.

Comment: I've updated my original post with a description of what I'm seeing and I've added an action to my Intent, which increased my share options but did not fix the file issue.

Comment: @TimvandeWal: I found another bug -- see my updated answer.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!